# Which national identity card number should I enter in a UK Student Visa application as an Indian UAE resident?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, uae, student-visas

I am an Indian citizen resident in the UAE, and I am currently applying for a student visa in the UK. What ID number should I enter on the visa application form: my Emirates ID or my Aadhar Card? Will answering that I o not have any national ID number affect my application?

Comment: Saying no to what, exactly?

Comment: No to having a national ID that can act as an internal passport

Answer (score 5):

If you are an Indian citizen, enter your Aadhar Card number.

If you are a UAE citizen, use your Emirates ID number.

Comment: Passport number will suffice I think. Aadhar is still not technically mandatory in India, especially for NRIs.